# Символы в тексте мешают валидации

Tags: php, xml

При генерации xml, иногда в него попадает информация, которая содержит какие-то html-картинки (скрин), и по итогу - ошибка при валидации xml .

Подскажите, как исключать подобные символы ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: удалить не utf-8 символы и всего делов

Comment: приведите конкретный пример, а также укажите кодировку